# script to copy multiple files from multiple directories to one of the folder/directory

Tags: grep, cp

I'm having five different directories in the `home` path which contain some files in all directories, as shown below.

`home/dir1` contains:

```
abc121219.txt
kucj.txt
gtuj120518.txt
gdkmcg.txt
such.txt
```

`home/dir2` contains:

```
itfhh.txt
jdjn.txt
iejb.txt
rub.pdf
gejb. txt
```

`home/dir3` contains:

```
duk.txt
jh.txt
```

`home/dir4` contains:

```
eubv.txt
jfhnb.txt
krti.txt
sk.pdf
```

`home/dir5` contains:

```
euhv.txt
idb.txt
grfb.pdf
urg.txt
```

Here, I want to copy some files from this different directory to another directory, which is directory 6, i.e. `/home/dir6`.

Like this:

```
cp home/dir1/gtuj120518.txt  home/dir6
cp home/dir1/such.txt    home/dir6
cp home/dir2/rub.pdf    home/dir6
cp home/dir3/duk.txt    home/dir6
cp home/dir4/jfhnb.txt    home/dir6
cp home/dir4/sk.pdf     home/dir6
cp home/dir5/idb.txt      home/dir6
```

So here every time I want write this command again and again.

Is there a script or short command I can use to copy multiple files from multiple directories to one of the folder/directory?

Comment: is there some pattern that identifies the files you want to copy?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Unless the OP wants to modify the question we don't have enough information to give an intelligent answer. The original question indicated a total of five directories but in a comment to my now-downvoted answer, the number of directories is now closer to 7500. You would need not just a pattern applied to the files to be copied but also a pattern to the 7500 different directories. Error handling in the case of file name collisions is necessary in a file move of this magnitude.

Answer (score -1):

First answer is "what have you tried?"

Second answer is "history is your friend"

Third answer is

```
echo cp -f home/dir1/gtuj120518.txt home/dir1/such.txt home/dir2/rub.pdf home/dir3/duk.txt home/dir4/jfhnb.txt home/dir4/sk.pdf home/dir5/idb.txt home/dir6 > ~/bin/cp_files
chmod 0700 ~/bin/cp_files
```

Then the command `~/bin/cp_files` will copy everything over.

Fourth answer, will symbolic links work for what you're looking for?

Comment: this is fine, but I'm having total 7,500 directories with every folder contain lots of files from them I want to pick

Comment: @PravinGaddam Since your question said you had `5` directories to copy files from, the answer was based on that. With a *much*  larger number of directories to choose from, you'll need to pick out some pattern in the files that you can feed to `find` or else have a large static of directory/filenames to feed to a script.